# Firebase plane downgrade

Tags: firebase

I bought the Flame plane for this month (20/01/2019).
Will it expire the 20/02/2019 or it will expire at the end of month?
If I want to do a downgrade, will I lose my Flame plane for this month or Spark plane will be active the next month?

Comment: I think this question should be asked to Firebase team or customer support instead

Comment: Please send your questions about billing directly to Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/